# Mock rootView of Caliburn.Micro WindowManager

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, caliburn.micro

Given I have a method like this:

```
public void ShowDialog()
{
  TestViewModel vm = new TestViewModel();
  _windowManager.ShowDialog(vm);
  DialogResultTest = vm.CoolText;
}
```

Now I want to write a test. In that test I want to inject a prepared `TestViewModel` into the `ShowDialog(vm)` method. My code looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestShowDialog()
{
  TestViewModel mockVM = new TestViewModel();
  mockVM.CoolText = "test";

  Mock<IWindowManager> wmMock = new Mock<IWindowManager>();
  wmMockSetup(w => w.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()))
                   .Returns(true)
                   .Callback<object, object, IDictionary<string, object>>((vm, obj, dic) =>
                   {
                     vm = mockVM;
                   });

  MainViewModel mainVM = new MainViewModel(wmMock.Object);
  mainVM.ShowDialog();
  Assert.That(mainVM.DialogResultText, Is.EqualTo("test");
}
```

The problem is, the `CoolText` I set in the test is gone after the actual `_windowManager.ShowDialog(vm)` call (`DialogResultText` is empty). It seems as if the `mockVM` is only used for the actual invocation of `_windowManager.ShowDialog(vm)` but is replaced with the original `vm` after.

Is there a way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are manually instantiating the `TestViewModel` the in the method under test so there is no easy way for you to manipulate its behavior during tests. You would have to be able to inject it into the target class as an explicit dependency just as you do the `IWindowManager`

Another way would be to use the call back to update the property of the actual view model that was passed in as an argument when the mocked member was invoked.

```
//Arrange
var expected = "test";
var wmMock = new Mock<IWindowManager>();
wmMock.Setup(w => 
    w.ShowDialog(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<IDictionary<string, object>>()))
      .Returns(true)
      .Callback<object, object, IDictionary<string, object>>((obj1, obj2, dic) => {
          var vm = obj1 as TestViewModel;
          if(vm ! = null) 
              vm.CoolText = expected;
      });

var mainVM = new MainViewModel(wmMock.Object);

//Act
mainVM.ShowDialog();

//Assert
Assert.That(mainVM.DialogResultText, Is.EqualTo(expected);
```

Comment: This probably is the right way to go and I will mark this as the answer for others with the same problem. I tried it like this before but there are reasons I can't do this in my real application unfortunately